# Auto lead generaton from incoming email

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-9

Auto lead generation from email is generating the leads but the mail coming from email address is storing in **email_from** field,How can I remove that auto filling the email address filling from it.I want that field should be empty.Can anybody know help me.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

You have to set up a incoming mail server(Setting > Technical > Email > Incoming mail server) where you have to give your email server information. and set value for field **Create a New Record** to **Lead/Opportunity**. after that test & confirm the record. it will fetch the email from the particulate email account and create lead in Odoo.

[image]